# Need help in connecting MongoDB to VS Code

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code

I am finding it very difficult to work on the MongoDB database in VS Code, as I am unable to connect MongoDB to VS Code. Could someone help me do it?

Answer (score 1):

I installed the **[MongoDB for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mongodb.mongodb-vscode)** plugin which handles Database Navigator, CRUD operations and other MongoDB commands directly inside VS Code.

You can get in-depth information about **MongoDB for VS Code** in this [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-vscode/).

### [Connect to Your MongoDB Deployment](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-vscode/connect)

[image]

### [Navigate your MongoDB Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-vscode/databases-collections)

[image]

Comment: Can I connect my local mongo DB with this extension, I tried it but it keeps on connecting..

Comment: @YashRahurikar From the above example, I connected my local MongoDB precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install MongoDB and create the Azure CosmosDB Extension. To install the extension just open the Extensions view in visual studio code by pressing Ctrl+Shift+X and search for 'cosmos' to filter the results then select the Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB extension.

Now assuming you are working with node js, you can test the connection as follows:

`mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/your-db-name', {})
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));`

For more information refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/mongodb)